# CRM solution import failed "an item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a strange behaviour in one of our CRM-Organizations.

When I export a solution (which only contains the account-entity) as an unmanaged solution it works.

But when I reimport this very same solution without changing anything I get this error

"an item with the same key has already been added".

I found out that I have to remove the Attribute "ownerid" from the solution (and one relationship) and then it works...

this is the attribute

```
    <attribute PhysicalName="OwnerId">
          <Type>owner</Type>
          <Name>ownerid</Name>
          <LogicalName>ownerid</LogicalName>
          <RequiredLevel>systemrequired</RequiredLevel>
          <DisplayMask>ValidForAdvancedFind|ValidForForm|ValidForGrid|RequiredForForm</DisplayMask>
          <ImeMode>auto</ImeMode>
          <ValidForReadApi>1</ValidForReadApi>
          <ValidForCreateApi>1</ValidForCreateApi>
          <IsCustomField>0</IsCustomField>
          <IsAuditEnabled>1</IsAuditEnabled>
          <IsSecured>0</IsSecured>
          <IntroducedVersion>5.0.0.0</IntroducedVersion>
          <SourceType>0</SourceType>
          <LookupStyle>single</LookupStyle>
          <LookupTypes>
            <LookupType id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">8</LookupType>
            <LookupType id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">9</LookupType>
          </LookupTypes>
          <displaynames>
            <displayname description="Vertriebsverantwortlicher" languagecode="1031" />
            <displayname description="Owner" languagecode="1033" />
            <displayname description="Właściciel" languagecode="1045" />
          </displaynames>
          <Descriptions>
            <Description description="Geben Sie den Benutzer oder das Team ein, der bzw. das mit der Verwaltung des Datensatzes betraut ist. Dieses Feld wird aktualisiert, wenn der Datensatz einem anderen Benutzer zugewiesen wird." languagecode="1031" />
            <Description description="Enter the user or team who is assigned to manage the record. This field is updated every time the record is assigned to a different user." languagecode="1033" />
            <Description description="Wprowadź nazwę użytkownika lub zespołu, który zarządza rekordem. To pole jest aktualizowane za każdym razem, gdy rekord zostanie przypisany do innego użytkownika." languagecode="1045" />
          </Descriptions>
        </attribute>
```

I also checked the serverlogs and found this:

```
<importexportxml start="635818108905329459" stop="635818109069971342" progress="22.2222222222222" processed="true">
<solutionManifests>
    <solutionManifest languagecode="1031" id="Firma_Transfer" LocalizedName="Firma_Transfer" processed="true">
        <UniqueName>Firma_Transfer</UniqueName>
        <LocalizedNames>
            <LocalizedName description="Firma_Transfer" languagecode="1031" />
        </LocalizedNames>
        <Descriptions />
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <Managed>0</Managed>
        <Publisher>
            <UniqueName>myorg</UniqueName>
            <LocalizedNames>
                <LocalizedName description="Myorg" languagecode="1031" />
            </LocalizedNames>
            <Descriptions />
            <EMailAddress />
            <SupportingWebsiteUrl />
            <Addresses>
                <Address>
                    <City />
                    <Country />
                    <Line1 />
                    <Line2 />
                    <PostalCode />
                    <StateOrProvince />
                    <Telephone1 />
                </Address>
            </Addresses>
        </Publisher>
        <results />
        <result result="success" errorcode="0" errortext="" datetime="13:08:12.07" datetimeticks="635818072920798192" />
    </solutionManifest>
</solutionManifests>
<upgradeSolutionPackageInformation>
    <upgradeRequired>0</upgradeRequired>
    <upgradeValid>1</upgradeValid>
    <fileVersion>7.0.1.129</fileVersion>
    <currentVersion>7.0.1.129</currentVersion>
    <fileSku>OnPremise</fileSku>
    <currentSku>OnPremise</currentSku>
</upgradeSolutionPackageInformation>
<entities>
    <entity LocalizedName="Firma" OriginalName="Firma" Description="" id="Account" processed="true">
        <result result="failure" errorcode="0x80044150" errortext="Ein Element mit dem gleichen Schlüssel wurde bereits hinzugefügt." datetime="13:08:26.96" datetimeticks="635818073069658863" />
    </entity>
</entities>
<nodes />
<settings />
<dashboards />
<securityroles />
<workflows />
<templates />
<optionSets />
<ConnectionRoles />
<SolutionPluginAssemblies />
<SdkMessageProcessingSteps />
<ServiceEndpoints />
<webResources />
<reports />
<FieldSecurityProfiles />
<convertrules />
<routingrules />
<Slas />
<languages>
    <language>
        <result result="success" errorcode="0" errortext="" datetime="13:08:11.07" datetimeticks="635818072910798185" />
    </language>
</languages>
<entitySubhandlers>
    <savedQuery LocalizedName="Firma" OriginalName="Firma" Description="" id="Account" processed="false"/>
    <formXml LocalizedName="Firma" OriginalName="Firma" Description="" id="Account" processed="false">
    </formXml>
    <entityCustomResources LocalizedName="Firma" OriginalName="Firma" Description="" id="Account" processed="false"/>
    <entityRibbon LocalizedName="Firma" OriginalName="Firma" Description="" id="Account" processed="false"/>
    <savedQueryVisualization LocalizedName="Firma" OriginalName="Firma" Description="" id="Account" processed="false">
    </savedQueryVisualization>
</entitySubhandlers>
<rootComponents>
    <rootComponent processed="false" />
</rootComponents>
<dependencies>
    <dependency processed="false" />
</dependencies>
```

All I found in the internet pointed to an problem with an attribute (missmatching type, ...) but in my case this is the same organization and no transfer from dev to prod or something like that...

We are using CRM 2015 but we had this problem in 2011 already.

Has anybody a solution for this? we don't want to edit the customization.XML everytime before importing a solution...

this is the database-field

```
[OwnerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_AccountBase_OwnerId]  DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

thanks

Tobias

Comment: Have you tried importing a vanilla account from another environment?

Comment: no not yet. when I import a vanilla account from another organization it will this not break my forms?

Comment: Yes, it would. I would suggest exporting account first from your primary environment so you can re-import afterwards to restore the forms. However you then run into the risk you can't re-import. Bit of a catch 22.

Answer (score 0):

Your database field for OwnerId looks fine. Delete any custom fields with common names from your destination organization and try the import again. For instance, if you have new_LastEmailDate on both, or any custom field that performs the same function as a custom field in the solution, delete it from the destination. One of your custom fields is being recognized as a new addition of an existing field, probably due to capitalization. If you're writing it in from the new solution, you don't need it in the destination anyway and a non-conflicting copy will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This happens for me when I try to reinstall a CRM 2016 Outlook that has been offline with a previous version of CRM. Uninstalling CRM and SQL server related items, cleaning up the registry deleting all folder and files related to the installation. I think it's worth mentioning that the installations works against the same CRM environment on other PC's.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is very generic, but the fact that you know which attribute is causing the issue makes things a lot easier.  It is usually possible to fix this type of issue by making direct database changes to repair corrupted metadata (unsupported!), but it requires a SQL developer with decent knowledge of how the CRM metadata tables work.  If you have such a person I could provide additional guidance, otherwise you should create a case with Microsoft.